# Xcode iPhone App error on launch: NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

What does this error mean exactly and how do I fix it?

```
2011-08-10 12:06:54.116 ScanTest[973:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ScanTestAppDelegate 0x190970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navigationController.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x36d0d64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33f66c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x36d0d3cd -[NSException dealloc] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x3511eedb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 182
    4   Foundation                          0x350d79cb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 90
    5   Foundation                          0x350d7217 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 194
    6   Foundation                          0x350b942f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 130
    7   UIKit                               0x35cfd8df -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 66
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x36ca5d7b -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 18
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x36ca599d -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 388
    10  UIKit                               0x35cfc847 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 586
    11  UIKit                               0x35cfde09 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 92
    12  UIKit                               0x35b284cd -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 96
    13  UIKit                               0x35b22b09 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 180
    14  UIKit                               0x35af77d7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
    15  UIKit                               0x35af7215 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
    16  UIKit                               0x35af6c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x36431e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x36ce4a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x36ce683f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x36ce760d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x36c77ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x36c77dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    23  UIKit                               0x35b21d49 -[UIApplication _run] + 372
    24  UIKit                               0x35b1f807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    25  ScanTest                            0x000037fb main + 70
    26  ScanTest                            0x00002e44 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Here is my didFinishLaunching method in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    [viewController release];

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainWindow.xib is missing an outlet for `navigationController`, even though it's still being connected. Either re-add the `IBOUtlet` to your AppDelegate.h, or disconnect the outlet from the XIB.

Comment: how do you do either of those? I've never used XIB and I don't want to use any XIB in this project.

Comment: What template did you create this from? All templates include at least a MainWindow.XIB, and if you've deleted that, that will definitely cause the issue. You'll have to restore the file, remove the outlet, then you can delete again. Is there any particular reason you have an aversion to XIBs? They don't hurt anything and make UI design much easier.

Comment: So you figured it out? What was the issue?

Comment: I basically ended up using the XIB but just deleted all the components from it, so that the xib was basically a blank screen. Then, I added components on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your `MainWindow.xib` is trying to attach an outlet `navigationController` to the app delegate. You must have removed the outlet after setting up the xib.

Answer (score 0):

your code write like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after app launch    

    MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    [viewController release];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];


    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

now this works..